# cc is not delivering

Tags: smtp, pear, php

I send email from php script by smtp server. I have used the header array like this:

```
$headers = array(
                'From'          => $from,
                'To'            => $email,
                'Cc'            => 'myemail@mydomain.com',
                'Return-Path'   => $sender,
                'Subject'       => $subject
                );
//sending process using smtp
$mail =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtp_params);
$result = $mail->send($email, $headers, $body);
```

The email is sent successfully and delivered to $email and I can see the cc header to myemail@mydomain.com in the received header. But the cc is not delivered to myemail@mydomain.com.

Can anybody tell me why this is happening. I have SPF record for my own domain and gmail mx server in one SPF syntax.
Regards

Comment: If I set myemail@mydomain.com in $email, i.e $email=myemail@mydomain.com with no cc, the email is sent to myemail@mydomain.com successfully.

Answer (score 0):

First argument passed to `$mail->send` specifies ALL recipients.

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php

Try:

```
$result = $mail->send(array($email, 'myemail@mydomain.com'), $headers, $body);
```